# Pass input into Java console launched by a Bash script

Tags: bash, java

Please note, I did not write any of these script, Java code, or the application and I am restricted as to what I can modify in these scripts.

I have a Bash script that starts a Java console `/foo/bar/myscript.sh`. Specified inside, it calls to start the Java console but prompts for a password before the shell is launched. I am trying to pass a command into the Java console that executes a backup procedure for an application.

Is there a way to run the script which passes the password? The password is not set via Bash but somewhere in Java and I don't know the variable name.

Is there also a way to pass the Java method in the same line? This is the normal, manual process:

1. `./myScript.sh`
2. `Please enter password: myPassword`
3. `javaConsole % backup.method("/backup/dir");`

Obviously this isn't correct but ideally, a command would go like this:
`echo myPassword | ./myscript.sh | backup.method("/backup/dir");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expect, probably, as this can spawn your script, answer the password prompt, and then I'm not sure what your Java console prompt looks like or what exactly it expects, but:

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
spawn -noecho ./myScript.sh
expect -ex password
send -raw "Hunter2\r"
expect -ex javaConsole
send -raw "backup.method(\"/backup/dir\");\r"
# and either you'll need to wait or interact with the java
# to keep it running...
interact
```

You could also run a trial session with `autoexpect` and then see what that generates for automation.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'myPassword
/backup/dir' | /foo/bar/myscript.sh
```

Comment: The problem with this is it needs to be invoked in a single command strung together. The above solution seems to work. The application I'm launching is quirky.